# Swift - PFObject return itself from save calback instead of bool

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app, pfobject

Just wonder if I can save parse `PFObject` in background and return it in callback instead of `Bool`.

```
parseObject.saveInBackground {
                  (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
                  if (success) {
                    completion(.success(true))
                  } else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: "OURTEAM", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Save invoice failure"])
                    completion(.failure(error))
                  }
                }
```

or do I need to re fetch object one more time from remote?

Comment: Yes.  It is your code.  You can declare the `Result` passed to `completion` as `Result<PFObject,Error>` if you like.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for comments but saveInBackground has this definition: `typedef void (^PFBooleanResultBlock)(BOOL succeeded, NSError *_Nullable error);`

Comment: You aren't changing `saveInBackground` - You are changing the signature of `completion` - which presumably was passed into the function that is calling `saveInBackground`, so `completion(.success(parseObject))`

Comment: oh you mean the instance object I just saved in the background this is what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why you would need the have that object in the callback when you already have the updated instance.

For example, the parseObject which you are saving is the updated instance once your callback completes, so just reference that.

You will see that after the save completes that parseObject which you previously had in memory has now been assigned an objected (assuming you created a new object and saved)